# regular expression in java to print after n characters

Tags: java, regex

I am writing java code to print something between two expressions.

My file from where I am reading is:

```
 CAL|AB12345|hi, how are you }
```

my java code:

```
final Pattern pattern = Patter.compile("CAL|AB[0-9]{5}|(.+?)}", Pattern.DOTALL);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(filename);
while (matcher.find()) {
 String a = matcher.group(0);
  System.out.println(a);}
```

I want the output to be:

```
hi, how are you
```

ALso, how can i calculate the number of characters for example if i want to print after 9 characters after CAL, it will also work.

Comment: Does [this](https://regex101.com/r/9ey3SO/1) help?[Code](https://onlinegdb.com/B1g4H0M3U)

Comment: You have to escape the pipe to match it. The value is in capturing group 1 `String regex = "CAL\\|AB[0-9]{5}\\|([^\\}\\r\\n]+)\\}";` https://regex101.com/r/3dahos/1

Answer (score 1):

you can modify your code like this :

```
public static void main(String []args){

    final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(CAL\\|AB[0-9]{5}\\|)([a-zA-Z0-9,><@#\\s]+)(})");
    final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("CAL|AB12345|hi, how are you }");

    String a;
    while (matcher.find()) {
         a = matcher.group(2);

        System.out.println(a);}
}
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
 hi, how are you
```

**Hint :** for  9 characters part ,you can start substring from that index count

Hope it helps !

Comment: You can do the stuff with regex only. No need to use `replaceFirst()` and `trim()` methods